# Set value of string to first element of array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

For a given document, I am attempting to set a field (string) as the first element of an array of strings. Consider a collection `myPlaces` with the following document:

```
{
    "name" : "Place Q",
    "images" : [
        "foo-1",
        "foo-2",
        "foo-3"
    ]
}
```

I am looking to create the following:

```
{
    "name" : "Place Q",
    "images" : [
        "foo-1",
        "foo-2",
        "foo-3"
    ],
    "image" : "foo-1"
}
```

So in the mongo shell, I execute:

```
db.myPlaces.update(
   {
      name: "Place Q"
   },
   {
      $set:
         {
            image: images.0
         }
   }
)
```

This throws the error `SyntaxError: missing } after property list` which I don't understand. If I enclose the array in quotes `"images.0"` the value of `image` is set as `"images.0"`, not `"foo-1"`.

I've been reviewing the Mongodb documentation and see a lot of different examples but not something that makes clear to me what is probably a simple syntax for accessing an array value.

Answer (score 4):

The following query works on MongoDB 4.2, It might not work on previous versions.

```
db.myPlaces.update(
  {
    name: "Place Q"
  },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        image: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$images",0]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

It's also very efficient as it is using $set pipeline provided in MongoDB 4.2+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please :

```
db.myPlaces.update(
    {
        name: "Place Q"
    },{
        $set:
            {
                image: db.myPlaces.find( { "images.0" } )
            }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do is:

- Find the document first.
- Iterate on that (You must have only one value, but it will work for multiple documents as well)
- Update document.

> Note:- Efficient for the small records. Bulk record will have lots of traffic on DB.
>
> ===== **Will work for all version of MongoDB** ======

**Data Before:**

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d53fda5f5fc3d6486b42fec"),
        "name" : "Place Q",
        "images" : [ 
            "foo-1", 
            "foo-2", 
            "foo-3"
        ]
    }
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.find({ name: "Place Q" }).forEach(function(document) {
    db.collection.update(
        {}, 
        { "$set": { "image": document.images[0] } }
    );
})
```

**Data After**

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d53fda5f5fc3d6486b42fec"),
        "name" : "Place Q",
        "images" : [ 
            "foo-1", 
            "foo-2", 
            "foo-3"
        ],
        "image" : "foo-1"
    }
```